# The tags bit-shift and bitwise-shift should probably be synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The (somewhat obscure) tags [bit-shift](/questions/tagged/bit-shift) and [bitwise-shift](/questions/tagged/bitwise-shift) should be synonyms of one another. It's mostly arbitrary, but I'd say [bitwise-shift](/questions/tagged/bitwise-shift) should be a synonym of [bit-shift](/questions/tagged/bit-shift), both the [GCC C Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Bit-Shifting) and the [AMD64 manual<sup>[PDF]</sup>](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/24594_APM_v3.pdf) call them that way. ([MSDN's C++ reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx) says otherwise.)

Comment: Wow that was fast